# Why does moment.js return this date wrong?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm simply trying to take an input string and convert it to a date object.

`moment.utc('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z').toDate()`

But it returns this...

`Fri Dec 31 1999 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: that *is* the right date/time. `00:00:00 UTC` (aka `00:00:00.000Z`) *is* `19:00:00 EST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid JavaScript Date Object. You can test this by opening a console in Chrome or Firefox, then entering the following:

```
// Mon Nov 24 2014 09:54:00 GMT-0800 (PST) (looks the same as your example)
console.log( new Date() );
```

If you want to format the value coming out of moment.js, you can use its format method and a mask.

```
// Example: November 24th 2014, 09:58:12am
var fdate = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

Moment.js doesn't modify the prototype, it simply wraps it.

If you want to convert a string to a date object using moment.js, you can just call it as such:

```
moment(your_date); // Unless in UTC mode this will display as local time
```

In your instance you're using the [UTC mode](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Answer (score 0):

`2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` is the GMT date/time.

Using `moment.utc("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toDate()` returns this date/time according to your timzone settings.

See : http://www.digitoffee.com/programming/get-local-time-utc-using-moment-js/94/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wrote the answer in the same time the comment was edited... Just trying to help.